# Google Actions- Output response is repeating in loop

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

[image][image]I'm facing an issue which is output response repeating in loop even after enabling end of conversation for particular intent request.This scenario appears when user ask for particular request, output response is send back to user which is end of conversation.But if the user doesn't ask for any other request still the mic is open,then previous output response starts repeating.
Why this scenario is occurring?

Comment: Is it through dialogflow or your webhook?

Comment: show the intent screenshot and webhook code if you have.

Comment: Its happening when testing with mini device not in simulator@NickFelker

Comment: Here i attached screenshot image but i can't share webhook code @AbhinavTyagi

Comment: whether this effects due to lifespan in output context or what?I have a doubt regarding this

Comment: Try to handle "No Input" using event - actions_intent_NO_INPUT. end the conversation for that as well or prompt the user for a safe exit.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Abhinav Tyagi

Comment: If it helped then upvote and accept as solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are setting the "End of conversation" switch for the Intent in the Dialogflow configuration, but you're also using fulfillment. In these cases, your webhook code overrides the settings for "end of conversation".

You can use your webhook to set the end of conversation. If you're using the actions-on-google library, then you can use `conv.close()` instead of `conv.ask()` to indicate this.

While it isn't a problem, it also doesn't really make sense that you're setting an Output Context when you're also closing the conversation. The Output Context will be ignored. (The Output Context also isn't set if you set Contexts from your webhook.)

Comment: It was my mistake that i didn't removed the context but i got solution from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49395582/hooking-into-the-actions-intent-no-input-in-dialogflow @Prisoner