# Handling of NO USER INPUT in dialogflow

Tags: google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, conversational-ui

I have an intent "Reprompt" in my agent with event value as "actions_intent_NO_INPUT" and Action value as no.input but still my agent triggers "Default Fall back intent" in case of no user input. I need help to understand how to have my agent identified no user input and fired "Reprompt" intent instead of "Default Fall back intent". Please note that I am building it for call center not for Google Assistant and currently testing it on a landline telephone set. Is this happening because dialogflow can't recognize no.input on mobile phones and landlines?

Comment: Hey, This answer may help you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49395582/hooking-into-the-actions-intent-no-input-in-dialogflow

Answer (score 0):

Is your "Reprompt" in a 'Catch Node'?  We use a Catch Node to catch things like "repeat", "silence" and low confidence checks.  If the customer asks for a repeat or hits silence (based on time count with no input) we increase a counter by +1 then repeat the initial phrase/question.  If silence again we increase the counter by +1 again.  On the 3rd try, we bounce them to an agent.  It should not matter if you are testing from a landline or mobile device.